# Count not null in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `A` with column data:

```
mdr1222
-------
pprgd24
-------
invalid
-------
invalid
abc2345
```

I want to get a count of the invalid and blank(---). I tried :

```
SELECT count(data)
from A
where data = 'invalid' and  null
```

but it doesn't work. Can someone please help me figure out what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: read about "IS NULL" statement, IFNULL() and COALESCE() functions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work as well.

```
SUM(CASE WHEN data IS NULL OR data = 'Invalid' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM A
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select count(column_name) from table_name where column_name is not null
```

returns number of rows where `column_name` value is not `null`

```
select count(column_name) from table_name where column_name is null
```

returns number of rows where `column_name` value is `null`